# travis CI example for GAE php

Tags: php, google-app-engine, travis-ci

can you give me an example of .travis.yml file for a PHP project on google cloud app engine ,

i have the following .travis.yml , but it fail to build :
https://github.com/Ali-aqrabawi/celis/blob/master/.travis.yml

if i do pull request the build fails with error :
incorrect usage for phpunit command.

if i remove the language php , i get the following error :
0.09s$ rake
rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The command "rake" exited with 1.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example.

https://github.com/tomwalder/php-gds/blob/master/.travis.yml

You'll also need to check out the composer file and phpunit.xml

Good luck!